# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't work properly after going fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I embedded MPMoviePlayerController like this:

```
[_mediaPlayerView addSubview:moviePlayer.view]; 
[self addChildViewController:moviePlayer];
```

Video plays ok. When i tap on fullscreen button player maximizes, but i see only control buttons, screen is blank. Loading indicator is spinning. When i unmaximize, embedded video controller is blank too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right way to embed MPMoviePlayerController:

```
        self.mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
        [self.mediaPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
        [self.mediaPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
        [self.mediaPlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
        [self.mediaPlayer prepareToPlay];

        [self.mediaPlayer.view setFrame:self.mediaPlayerView.bounds];
        [self.mediaPlayerView addSubview:self.mediaPlayer.view];
        self.mediaPlayerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```